# What are the requirements to convert an FAA certificate to EASA/JAA?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, easa-regulations

If a pilot holding a US certificate wanted to convert it to an equivalent EASA (JAA?) certificate, what training, flight experience, and exams are necessary to obtain equivalency?

Does the process differ for private, instrument, commercial, ATP, and instructor ratings?

Comment: We had three guys converting FAA licenses to EASA here in 2013. The CAA decided on a specific conversion program for each candidate based on type of license, experience, etc. All three had to take all 14 ATPL theory exams. Actual flight training varied around 10 to 15 hours in a SEP and about 3 hours in a MEP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Pondlife states, this will depend on each member state's implementation of the EASA rules but I would expect that the implementations would be similar -- otherwise what is the point of EASA?  (That would be a good question except it would no doubt be closed as being too "opinion based".)

I've added a link to the relevant UK documentation and marked this as a Community Wiki answer so that hopefully others can expand on this for other states and perhaps add personal experiences.

### UK

[CAP 804](https://www.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAA_CAP%20804.pdf) Section 4, Part Q deals with "Validation and Conversion of Non-EASA licences issued by States other than the UK".

Comment: @lnafziger managed to copy this answer just before you deleted your duplicate question!

Comment: Haha, good!  I delayed deleting it hoping that you would get it!

Answer (score 1):

I have no personal experience of this question but it is [included](https://easa.europa.eu/flightstandards/faq.html#thirdcountryconversion) in the EASA [Flight Standard FAQ](https://easa.europa.eu/flightstandards/faq.html). The key point seems to me to be this:

> The competent authority of the Member State to which an applicant
>   applies will determine the conversion requirements, which can be
>   reduced on the basis of a recommendation from an approved training
>   organisation.
>
> Therefore, the national aviation authority of the Member State where
>   an applicant resides or wishes to work should be contacted for further
>   information concerning the applicable acceptance requirements.

In other words, the exact requirements are determined locally by the EASA member state you live in and/or want to fly in. Perhaps someone who's actually been through the process could give a better answer.