# Can I get an EASA ATPL online?

Tags: easa-regulations, pilot-certification, atpl

I have a PPL license in the US and I want to do a European ATPL license.

How does it work? Do I have to attend a school or can I do all online?
Do I have to physically take the tests somewhere in Europe or can this be done somewhere online as well? How did the COVID-19 change these things?

Comment: @StephenS What do you mean get there in the first place? I understand that the schools changed their policy and canceled all frontal instruction to presentations / zoom sessions / PPT. But regarding the theory tests- you say it still has to be on-premise of the school. Another question- what are the requirements regarding flight lessons and experience needed in order to get the ATPL? Please don't give me the "A lot!!!' Answer. If you have specific numbers- answer. if not- don't bother. You can also consider me having hundreds of hours logged already, aside from my ppl license.

Comment: Actually, it is very different. For example, 14 theory tests in EASA, while it's 1/ 2 exams if the USA. next- in order to actually get the license (meaning unfrozen ATPL)- you do need to take flight exams. Do you know the exact numbers for that? Because I knew that it was a lot by myself also.

Comment: @StephenS but what about air force veterans for example? Havr you thought about that possibility? I know these forums are a good ground for ego, but what i actually was here for- ie proper and accurate information. Yes, i have a PPL. And no, you did not give me one exact answer, just tried to satisfy your own craving for picking a weird argument online instead of being helpful. Which is a real pitty for you. I am sorry

Comment: [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39/62) might be relevant; EASA delegates licensing to member states and they can have different requirements. I'm not sure what your focus is here: how/if you can get an EASA ATPL in the US; how/if you can get an EASA ATPL online; how/if you can use an FAA private certificate as 'credit' towards an EASA ATPL; or something else? I *think* you're mostly asking about online but if my edit was wrong then of course please roll back or edit again.

Comment: @Stan are your comments referring Stephens answer? If so, you should place them under the answer. Your dismay at his anwer is somewhat unjustified, as your original question was not asking for very specific info. You may edit the question to make it more specific. Bottom line is, as Stephen wrote: it will not be easy, nor possible online, not by a long shot. To add insult to injury, there is no shortage of professional pilots now or in the near future.

Comment: @Jpe61 I made some snarky comments that I’be since deleted and turned into a more polite answer, but his replies are still here.

Comment: @Jpe61 Look, The fact is that instead of actually trying to answer and supply for information (and it's pretty obvious what information I need), we got to condescending and teaching morals. Of course, you can't get the whole license online, that is understood by everyone. Question is- Can you do the whole program online, except for the exams? or maybe- the exams must be taken on-prem? The flight experience is another question, to which Pondlife gave a good answer, and at least tried to supply some information.

Answer (score 2):

**No, you can’t get an ATPL online.**

Your first step would be converting your FAA PPL to an EASA PPL. You will then need to add Instrument, Commercial Single-Engine, Commercial Multi-Engine, Multi-Crew Commercial and frozen ATP ratings. All of that will require ground instruction, flight instruction, written tests and checkrides. Then you will need to build time until 1500 hours to get your ATPL unfrozen. There are some differences in process and terminology between FAA and EASA, of course, but the end result will require roughly the same skills and experience because both systems have to meet the same ICAO standards.

COVID-19 has not changed the requirements to get a license, just the feasibility of actually meeting them. Many flight schools are closed, those that are open may not be accepting foreign students, and you may not be able to get there at all due to border restrictions.

Comment: S, I would argue that not everything you listed is a prerequisite for an ATP.  Unless you are sure that EASA is different than FAA...

Comment: @MichaelHall What do you think is unnecessary?

Comment: Well, I got an FAA ATP without ever having PPL, Commercial Single, or FAA Instrument Rating.  Yes, I was military, and the OP hints that he might be as well.  But, like you I am a bit put off by the way he asked the question, and his defensive response.

Comment: @MichaelHall He says “I have a PPL” in the question. Military pilots that start with a Multi CPL+IR can obviously skip the earlier steps.

Comment: Everything you mention is the “normal” progression of course, I am just pointing out that it doesn’t necessarily mean they are hard requirements.  If you amass 1500 hours as a Private pilot and can pass the ATP, why couldn’t you get it?

Comment: But if they are, add a reference to bolster your answer and I will upvote.

Comment: @MichaelHall That is my point- I do have a PPL which was acquired for recreational purposes. The flight hours are more than enough- I have more than 1500 hours logged. Now- for this situation- of course, the fact that I have an FAA PPl does not really help me a lot fo the European ATPL. Question is- with that experience, do I get any discounts regarding the flight experience? Will I have to do all the courses- IR, CPL, etc, or just the ATPL theories and exams? and Guys, don't get put off by my response. I am just trying to understand facts.

Comment: @Stan Those are critical details that should be included in your question. Yes, you get “credit” for the hours toward the time-building part. No, it doesn’t get you out of any other requirements.

Comment: Stephen, he did state in the question that he had a PPL.  And in his first comment he clarifies that he has hundreds of hours, so it is safe to presume that he understands that there is a minimum hour requirement.   And the question clearly is not asking what that flight hour minimum is.  I don’t know much about EASA, but surely there must be some document similar to our FAA CFRs that spell this out?

Comment: P.S.  I don’t even think that Stan’s background information matters.  If somebody asked what was required for an FAA ATP I could steer them to sub part G, or paraphrase an answer myself.  It would matter not if the asker was a commercial pilot with 2000 hours, or a school child writing a paper - the answer is the same.